# Caliburn.Micro view resolution for ViewModel<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am have come across a problem with CM, in that I cannot get it to resolve a view when the matching ViewModel contains generic type parameters.

For example, by convention a `FooViewModel` resolves to display a `FooView`; However from my experiments, a `FooViewModel<T>` does not.

Is this a supported scenario and I'm just missing something obvious? If not, does anyone know if there is a way to *coax* CM to do this using existing conventions or will I have to add to or override the default convention somehow?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might see this in the future, it seems I had been awake for far, far to long when I was tackling this problem last night.

Looking again at this now (after a bit of kip and a coffee) I can confirm that when CM encounters a generic ViewModel class such as `FooViewModel<T>`, it will resolve to display a `FooView`.

The reason why I couldn't get CM to resolve was due to the `FooViewModel<T>` class being located in the wrong namespace!! Changed the namespace to 'ViewModels' as per convention and viola! everything works.